Reformatting pdf text into dataframe to remove extra information
I am trying to load the text from a pdf into R for text analysis. The pdf is formatted so that the text has columns for extra information. Please see the screen shot below.

I'd like to load the main body of the text so I can create a corpus for analysis of collocates, keyness, etc. I'd like to compare this program note text to one from a century ago on the same piece, also written by the Chicago Symphony Orchestra.
This is the code that I currently have:
pdf.file <- "file:///C:/Users/ayaxi/Downloads/program.pdf"
download.file(pdf.file, destfile = "sample.pdf", mode = "wb")
pdf.text <- pdftools::pdf_text("sample.pdf") |>
  readr::read_lines()

tannhauser <- pdf.text[657:799]

This is what is read into R with just the above code.
enter image description here
I added
tannhauser |> str_squish()

This removes the extra spaces when the text is loaded into R, but I still don't know how to filter out the words and text from the columns so that I can just look at the main body of the text. Is there a way that I can do this?
I've tried to use str_remove_all with str_remove_all("\S{3,}[^\s]+\S{3,}") to remove all text surrounded by three or more spaces, but that removes words from the main text as well.

What you're asking is highly dynamic and likely involves different answers for each text you are parsing. Any solid answer will need an example to work on and unfortunately a picture of the data doesn't help because how should answerers work with them? See how-to make a minimal reproducible example.

Assuming it's the Program Book - Muti, Montgomery & Rachmaninov 2 of Chicago Symphony Orchestra, you could try pdftools::pdf_data().
pdf_data() returns a list of tibbles, one for each pdf page. Each textbox in pdf ends up in a tibble row and in this particular case each textbox contains just a single word. As tibbles also include positions (x, y) for every textbox, you can use x-location to filter words from correct column, grouping by y allows to build lines and changes in first x values of every line can be used to guess paragraphs (kind of works).
library(pdftools)
#> Using poppler version 23.08.0
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

f <- "Wrap4-CSO26-May-Jul23-self-cover-v7-Issuu.pdf"

# ?pdf_data() :
# one data frame per page, containing one row for each textbox in the PDF
page19 <- pdf_data(f)[[19]]

# every word is a separate textbox:
page19
#> # A tibble: 569 × 6
#>    width height     x     y space text    
#>    <int>  <int> <int> <int> <lgl> <chr>   
#>  1    73     19    26    25 TRUE  comments
#>  2    14     19   104    25 TRUE  by      
#>  3    46     19   123    25 TRUE  phillip 
#>  4    60     19   174    25 FALSE huscher 
#>  5    53     17    27    63 TRUE  richard 
#>  6    50     17    84    63 FALSE wagner  
#>  7    20     12    27    80 TRUE  Born    
#>  8    17     12    49    80 TRUE  May     
#>  9    11     12    69    80 TRUE  22,     
#> 10    18     12    82    80 TRUE  1813;   
#> # ℹ 559 more rows

# visualize textbox locations
plot(y ~ x, data = page19, ylim = rev(range(y)))


# main column is left of x = 300;
# group by y to get lines, keep first x value to guess paragraphs, collapse text;
page19 |> 
  filter(x < 300) |> 
  summarise(
    line_x = first(x), 
    line = paste(text, collapse = " "), 
    .by = y
  ) |> 
  mutate(par = cumsum(line_x > lag(line_x, default = 0))) |>  
  # check individual lines
  print() |> 
  # collapse lines by guessed paragraphs
  summarise(text = paste(line, collapse = " "), .by = par)
#> # A tibble: 44 × 4
#>        y line_x line                                          par
#>    <int>  <int> <chr>                                       <int>
#>  1    25     26 comments by phillip huscher                     1
#>  2    63     27 richard wagner                                  2
#>  3    80     27 Born May 22, 1813; Leipzig, Germany             2
#>  4    92     27 Died February 13, 1883; Venice, Italy           2
#>  5   109     27 Overture to Tannhäuser                          2
#>  6   153    110 Tannhäuser was once Wagner’s most               3
#>  7   165    110 popular opera. At the time of his death, it     3
#>  8   177    110 was staged more often than any of his other     3
#>  9   189    110 works and a bigger box-office draw than         3
#> 10   201    110 the later, groundbreaking music dramas—         3
#> # ℹ 34 more rows
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>     par text                                                                    
#>   <int> <chr>                                                                   
#> 1     1 comments by phillip huscher                                             
#> 2     2 richard wagner Born May 22, 1813; Leipzig, Germany Died February 13, 18…
#> 3     3 Tannhäuser was once Wagner’s most popular opera. At the time of his dea…
#> 4     4 Tannhäuser held a unique place in Wagner’s career. He revised and retho…
#> 5     5 a b o v e : Richard Wagner, in Paris, 1842. Sketch by friend Ernst Bene…


To a get a complete article as a single text vector, we can manually define top / bottom boundaries and ignored column locations for each page and just join all words.
Visualize boundaries:
withr::with_par(
  list(mfrow = c(1,3)),
  {
    plot(y ~ x, data = pages[[19]], ylim = rev(range(y)), asp = 1)
    abline(v = 300, h = c(110, 600), col = "red")
    plot(y ~ x, data = pages[[20]], ylim = rev(range(y)), asp = 1)
    abline(h = c(50, 600), col = "red")
    plot(y ~ x, data = pages[[21]], ylim = rev(range(y)), asp = 1)
    abline(h = c(50, 300), col = "red")
  }
)


Location filters for each page, bind remaining rows, join all words and deal with hyphens:
pages <- pdf_data(f)
bind_rows(
  filter(pages[[19]], between(y, 110, 600), x < 300),
  filter(pages[[20]], between(y,  50, 600)),
  filter(pages[[21]], between(y,  50, 300)),
) |> 
  pull(text) |> 
  str_c(collapse = " ") |> 
  str_remove_all("- ") |> 
  # just for compact output
  str_trunc(400, side = "center", ellipsis = "/ ... /") |> 
  str_wrap() |> 
  cat()
#> Tannhäuser was once Wagner’s most popular opera. At the time of his death, it
#> was staged more often than any of his other works and a bigger box-office draw
#> than the later, groundbreaking music dra/ ... /aiser, and so, for the only time
#> in the opera, the pilgrim’s noble march—the first music we hear—is played in E
#> major, Venus’s key borrowed for the purpose to make musical, if not dramatic,
#> sense.


This seems to be what you are looking for:
pdf.file <- "science.pdf"

pdf.text <- pdftools::pdf_text(pdf.file) |>
  readr::read_lines()

pdf.text <- pdf.text |> stringr::str_squish()

body <- c()
for(i in pdf.text){
  body <- c(body,paste(i, collapse = ""))
}

cat(body)

500 Spring Books Supplement Nature Vol. 296 8 April 1982 Toulmin and others he views science as a Science in society, society in science spectrum with the value-laden social and C.A. Russell human sciences at one end, but with the largely value-free physical sciences at the Between Science and Values. By Loren R. "restrictionists". The former hold that other. His carefully documented case- Graham. Pp.449. ISBN 0-231-05192-1. science and values did, and do, have much studies offer some support for the view (Columbia University Press: 1981.) $25.90, in common and, while in one sense there recently expressed (by D. M. MacKay) that £14.40. was no separate world "between" them, the notion of universally value-laden they were capable of the most potent science is an illogical extrapolation from SciENCE is about what is - what exists interactions that could have consequences the social sciences (where it is undoubtedly "out there" in the given world of nature.

